# Can I call an aura component in a lightning web component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, popup

Is it possible to call an aura component into a lightning web component?

I have an aura component and now i want to call it in a lightning web component as a popup.

I already have an aura component that is a form with questions to be answered that I validate. I've added it to the tab menu, but now I want to call this same aura component in a lightning web component as a pop up (I want to access this form when I launch a button). Is there a way to call my aura component from a lightning web component as a popup?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i tried to make it more clair , i modified my post , hope that is more specific .

Comment: No you can not add Aura component inside Lightning web component. [Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.interop_aura_composition)

Comment: @SarojBera This should be an answer.

Comment: @SarojBera  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/interop_intro):

> IMPORTANT Aura components can contain Lightning web components. However, the opposite doesn’t apply. Lightning web components can’t contain Aura components.

You'll have to rewrite your component as a LWC if you want to use it inside a LWC.

Comment: thanks  for your help

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. We can call the LWC component inside the Aura component but we cannot call the aura component in the LWC component.

Comment: So in which respect does this not repeat the answer given 5 months ago?